# Having trouble with Ruby versions - rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rbenv

I recently updated my computer to Mac OS X El Capitan and had to reinstall homebrew and rbenv.

When I go to bundle install in one of my rails app and run bundle install I get:                       "Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.0".

However, when I do ruby-v I get: ruby 2.2.0p0 . Why am I seeing two different versions and how can I change it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rbenv not using the correct version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849374/rbenv-not-using-the-correct-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rbenv -h will tell you what to do.

"rbenv versions"    List all Ruby versions available to rbenv

"rbenv global"      Set or show the global Ruby version

"rbenv local"       Set or show the local application-specific Ruby version

to set, just do "rbenv local 2.2.0" or "rbenv global 2.2.0"

Also, there is the .ruby-version file that can also set ruby version.

Look at the instructions from rbenv main github page for more info.  They do a pretty good job describing how to set the active ruby version.
https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must update your executables (`bundle install`), try this `rbenv rehash`. Take from [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-rehash)

`rbenv rehash` Installs shims for all Ruby executables known to rbenv (i.e., ~/.rbenv/versions/*/bin/*). Run this command after you install a new version of Ruby, or install a gem that provides commands.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of another question and you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53849574/3182171

For convenience I report also here.

Try with this.

In your rails project folder check the presence of `.ruby-version` file and put inside the same ruby version specified into Gemfile.
(if this file is not present, create it.)

**~/your-rails-project/.ruby-version** file:

```
2.2.0
```

**~/your-rails-project/Gemfile** file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.0'
...
```

Then install that version with rbenv:

```
$ rbenv install 2.2.0
$ rbenv rehash
$ rbenv local 2.2.0
$ rbenv global 2.2.0
```

Now check that you are using the right version with:

```
$ ruby -v
```

You can now execute

```
$ bundle install
```

Comment: You should flag the question as duplicate instead of posting the same thing again. Thanks.