# Rbenv not using the correct version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler, rbenv

In my rails project, when I try to run `bundle install`, I get the following error:

`Your Ruby version is 2.3.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.3`

However, when I run `ruby --version` I get:

`ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin18]`

...and running `rbenv version` gives me:

`2.5.3 (set by /Users/jamesmulholland/proj/repo-name/.ruby-version)`

***What is cauing this the wrong version of Ruby to be used here, and how do I fix it?***

---

#### Other Context and Failed Fixes

- Running `rbenv versions` gives:

  `` system
  2.5.3 (set by /Users/jamesmulholland/proj/repo-name/.ruby-version)` ``
- This issue has occurred during a move from Ruby 2.5.1 to Ruby 2.5.3. At the same time, I moved from rvm to rbenv. I suspect I may have uninstalled rvm incorrectly as I ran `rm -rf ~/.rvm` rather than `rvm implode` but `/etc/rbenv/` is empty and running `rvm` commands fails. `rvm` is removed from my `.zshrc`. When I continued to run into this issue after this method of uninstalling rvm, I reinstalled rvm and uninstalled using the `rvm implode` process in case there were any other traces of rvm left that were causing issues. This also failed to fix the issue.
- I completely removed the directory and pulled a fresh copy from GitHub. No success.
- Checking out an old commit does not fix the error (I get `Your Ruby version is 2.3.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1` instead)
- The application runs fine on my colleague's computer.
- Potentially relevant section of my .zshrc (the rvm equivalent is commented out):

  `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"`
- `.ruby-version` is 2.5.3
- `Gemfile` contains:

  `source 'https://rubygems.org'
  ruby "2.5.3"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this.

In your rails project folder check the presence of `.ruby-version` file and put inside the same ruby version specified into Gemfile.
(if this file is not present, create it.)

**~/your-rails-project/.ruby-version** file:

```
2.5.3
```

**~/your-rails-project/Gemfile** file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.5.3'
...
```

Then install that version with rbenv:

```
$ rbenv install 2.5.3
$ rbenv rehash
$ rbenv local 2.5.3
$ rbenv global 2.5.3
```

Now check that you are using the right version with:

```
$ ruby -v
```

Comment: My `Gemfile` and `.ruby-version` were correct, but it apperas I needed to run `rbenv rehash`. For anyone else trying, I ran `rbenv rehash` before but this did not work. My best guesses are that I needed to re-clone the repo, restart, or do something else to get this working.